# Optimize Enum Lookup Map

Tags: java, optimization, enums, hashmap, set

I am wondering if there is a better way to create and search through the static Maps below. As seen in the `main()` method.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public enum PokemonType {
  BUG("Bug"),
  DARK("Dark"),
  DRAGON("Dragon"),
  ELECTRIC("Electric"),
  FAIRY("Fairy"),
  FIGHTING("Fighting"),
  FIRE("Fire"),
  FLYING("Flying"),
  GHOST("Ghost"),
  GRASS("Grass"),
  GROUND("Ground"),
  ICE("Ice"),
  NORMAL("Normal"),
  POISON("Poison"),
  PSYCHIC("Psychic"),
  ROCK("Rock"),
  STEEL("Steel"),
  WATER("Water");

  private String name;

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  public static Map<PokemonType, Set<PokemonType>> noEffect = new HashMap<PokemonType, Set<PokemonType>>() {{
    put(BUG, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(DARK, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(DRAGON, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(ELECTRIC, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GROUND)); }});
    put(FAIRY, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(FIGHTING, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GHOST)); }});
    put(FIRE, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(FLYING, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(GHOST, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(NORMAL)); }});
    put(GRASS, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(GROUND, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FLYING)); }});
    put(ICE, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(NORMAL, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GHOST)); }});
    put(POISON, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(PSYCHIC, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(ROCK, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(STEEL, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(WATER, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
  }};

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  public static Map<PokemonType, Set<PokemonType>> notVeryEffective = new HashMap<PokemonType, Set<PokemonType>>() {{
    put(BUG, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FIGHTING,FIRE,FLYING,GHOST,POISON,STEEL)); }});
    put(DARK, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DARK,FIGHTING,STEEL)); }});
    put(DRAGON, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(STEEL)); }});
    put(ELECTRIC, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DRAGON,ELECTRIC)); }});
    put(FAIRY, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(FIGHTING, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(BUG,FLYING,POISON,PSYCHIC)); }});
    put(FIRE, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DRAGON,FIRE,ROCK,WATER)); }});
    put(FLYING, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(ROCK,STEEL)); }});
    put(GHOST, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(STEEL)); }});
    put(GRASS, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(BUG,DRAGON,FIRE,FLYING,GRASS,POISON,STEEL)); }});
    put(GROUND, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(BUG,GRASS)); }});
    put(ICE, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FIRE,ICE,STEEL,WATER)); }});
    put(NORMAL, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(ROCK,STEEL)); }});
    put(POISON, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GHOST,GROUND,POISON,ROCK)); }});
    put(PSYCHIC, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(PSYCHIC,STEEL)); }});
    put(ROCK, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FIGHTING,GROUND,STEEL)); }});
    put(STEEL, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(ELECTRIC,FIRE,STEEL,WATER)); }});
    put(WATER, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DRAGON,GRASS,WATER)); }});
  }};

  @SuppressWarnings("serial")
  public static Map<PokemonType, Set<PokemonType>> superEffective = new HashMap<PokemonType, Set<PokemonType>>() {{
    put(BUG, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DARK,GRASS,PSYCHIC)); }});
    put(DARK, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GHOST,PSYCHIC)); }});
    put(DRAGON, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DRAGON)); }});
    put(ELECTRIC, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FIRE,WATER)); }});
    put(FAIRY, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(FIGHTING, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DARK,ICE,NORMAL,ROCK,STEEL)); }});
    put(FIRE, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(BUG,GRASS,ICE,STEEL)); }});
    put(FLYING, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(BUG,FIGHTING,GRASS)); }});
    put(GHOST, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GHOST,PSYCHIC)); }});
    put(GRASS, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GROUND,ROCK,WATER)); }});
    put(GROUND, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(ELECTRIC,FIRE,POISON,ROCK,STEEL)); }});
    put(ICE, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(DRAGON,FLYING,GRASS,GROUND)); }});
    put(NORMAL, new HashSet<PokemonType>());
    put(POISON, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(GRASS)); }});
    put(PSYCHIC, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FIGHTING,POISON)); }});
    put(ROCK, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(BUG,FIRE,FLYING,ICE)); }});
    put(STEEL, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(ICE,PSYCHIC)); }});
    put(WATER, new HashSet<PokemonType>() {{ addAll(Arrays.asList(FIRE,GROUND,ROCK)); }});
  }};

  public float getModifier(PokemonType opponentType) {
    if (PokemonType.superEffective.get(this).contains(opponentType))
      return 2.0f;
    if (PokemonType.notVeryEffective.get(this).contains(opponentType))
      return 0.5f;
    if (PokemonType.noEffect.get(this).contains(opponentType))
      return 0.0f;
    return 1.0f;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public String shortName() {
    return this.name.substring(0, 3);
  }

  private PokemonType(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    assert(PokemonType.ELECTRIC.getModifier(PokemonType.WATER) == 2.0f);
    assert(PokemonType.GROUND.getModifier(PokemonType.DARK) == 1.0f);
    assert(PokemonType.FIRE.getModifier(PokemonType.DRAGON) == 0.5f);
    assert(PokemonType.NORMAL.getModifier(PokemonType.GHOST) == 0.0f);
  }
}
```

Comment: What are your requirements for "better"? (Is this about runtime performance? Readability? Having the compiler verify completeness? The ability to easily import the matrix from excel? Something else altogether?)

Answer (score 0):

I would use an [ImmutableMap](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ImmutableMap.html) or an [UnmodifiableMap](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections//javadocs/api-3.2.1/org/apache/commons/collections/map/UnmodifiableMap.html) since the map(s) aren't supposed to be modified once they've been populated.

Also, I would create a single `Map<List<PokemonType>, Float>`, where each list would contain two `PokemonType` objects (the first object would be the attacker and the second would be the defender, or vice versa - it doesn't matter as long as it's consistent).  Alternatively, I would create a single `Map<PokemonTypePair, Float>`, where `PokemonTypePair` is

```
public class PokemonTypePair {
    final public PokemonType attacker;
    final public PokemonType defender;

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(obj == null) return false;
        else if(!(obj instanceof PokemonTypePair)) return false;
        else {
            PokemonTypePair other = (PokemonTypePair)obj;
            return this.attacker.equals(other.attacker) &&
                this.defender.equals(other.defender);
        }
    }

    public int hashCode() {
        return (997 * attacker == null ? 0 : attacker.hashCode()) ^
            (991 * defender == null ? 0 : defender.hashCode());
    }
}
```

The the `float` for each map entry would be 0.0, 0.5, 1.0, or 2.0; alternatively, omit the map entries that would have a 1.0 value and assume that missing map entries correspond to a 1.0 value.

If the pairings are reflexive (meaning it doesn't matter who is the attacker and who is the defender - I don't know how pokemon works), then you just need a `PokemonType pokemon1` field and a `PokemonType pokemon2` field; put the PokemonType that's lower in alphabetical order in the `pokemon1` field and the PokemonType that's higher in alphabetical order in the `pokemon2` field, in order to simplify the `equals` method.  Likewise, if you go with the `List<List<PokemonType>>` approach, sort the inner list in alphabetical order, or else use a `List<Set<PokemonType>>` instead.

This way, given any two pokemon types, you just need to look up the pair in a single map to find the multiplier, rather than having to check multiple maps.

If you want to quickly find the pairings that are ineffective / super effective / etc, then maintain separate lists or sets of the ineffective / super effective / etc pairings, i.e. `List<List<PokemonType>> ineffectivePairing` or `List<PokemonPairing> ineffectivePairing`

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Map with an Enum key or a Set with enum values, it is more efficient to use an EnumMap or EnumSet as these are designed for this situation.